# Print Server Response

Tags: javascript, jquery, perl, httpresponse

I'm working with a form that validates in Perl. I'm able to see the response in chrome dev tools, under network, XHR. I would like to print the 'response' error.

It looks like this :

```
{type: "error", message: "Unable to located your account by this email address: tim@example.com"}
message:"Unable to located your account by this email address: tim@example.com"
type: "error"
```

and the header request looks like this :

```
/vsap/mail_id.html?email=tim%40example.com
```

Is there anyway I can access the error message with jQuery?

Comment: Can you post the JavaScript code you use to make the ajax request to perl?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I would recommend you to read the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/). I assume that's how you do the request to the server. You can provide a `fail()` callback that is documented [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). So, you should add after the call to get another one to `.fail(function(jqXHR, status, error){})` and inside that function do what you need with the error. Also, you can use status to treat different error types in different ways. The documentation for fail is:

> A function to be called if the request fails. The function receives
>   three arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object, a
>   string describing the type of error that occurred and an optional
>   exception object, if one occurred. Possible values for the second
>   argument (besides null) are "timeout", "error", "abort", and
>   "parsererror". When an HTTP error occurs, errorThrown receives the
>   textual portion of the HTTP status, such as "Not Found" or "Internal
>   Server Error." As of jQuery 1.5, the error setting can accept an array
>   of functions. Each function will be called in turn. Note: This handler
>   is not called for cross-domain script and JSONP requests. This is an
>   Ajax Event.